# Как отловить клик в canvas по нескольким элементам

Tags: javascript, canvas, click

```js
( Необходимо отловить клик по картинкам-'спутникам', по 'главным'  получилось легко, а по летающим вокруг не получается..) Фрагмент кода:

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
          var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
 
    var W = window.innerWidth,
         H = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.width  = W;
    canvas.height = H;
 
    var angle = 0;
    
    var currentAngle = 0;
    var TO_RADIANS = Math.PI / 180;
    var particles = [];
    var Lradius = 20;
    var radius = 80;
    var images = [массив с картинками "спутниками" ];
    
    function Particle() {
    this.images = images[i];
    this.radius = 20;
    this.radis = 80;
    this.x = Math.floor((Math.random() * canvas.width / 2) + this.radius*1.5);
    this.y = Math.floor((Math.random() * canvas.height / 2) + this.radius*1.5);
    
    this.speedx = Math.round((Math.random() * 101) + 0) / 100;
    this.speedy = Math.round((Math.random() * 101) + 0) / 100;
 
    this.move = function() {
 
    
        context.beginPath();
        context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
 
        context.save();
        context.translate(this.x, this.y);
        context.rotate(Gangle * TO_RADIANS);
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = 'img/bag.png';
        context.drawImage(image,20, -20, 40, 40);
        context.restore();
        angle+=0.1;

        for (var m = 0; m < this.images.length; m++) {  //картинки-"спутники" 
          var image2 = new Image();
          image2.src = this.images[m];
          var dist = Math.PI*2 /this.images.length;
          var pattern2 = context.createPattern(image2, "no-repeat");
          context.fillStyle = pattern2;
          var vx = Math.cos(dist*m+currentAngle) * (this.radius - 5);
          var vy = Math.sin(dist*m+currentAngle) * (this.radius - 5);
          context.drawImage(image2, (this.x -  this.Lradius) + vx, (this.y -  this.Lradius) + vy, this.Lradius*2, this.Lradius*2);
        
        }
    }
    };
 
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      var particle = new Particle();
        particles.push(particle);
    }
 
    function animate() {
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
        particles[i].move();
 
    }
      requestAnimFrame(animate);
    }
    animate();
    
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {// клик по 'главным' картинкам
        var xCoord = e.offsetX;
        var yCoord = e.offsetY;
  for( var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++ ){
  if((xCoord >= particles[i].x - particles[i].radius && xCoord <= particles[i].x + particles[i].radius) && (yCoord >= particles[i].y - particles[i].radius && yCoord <= particles[i].y + particles[i].radius)){

                var div = document.getElementById("div");
                div.innerHTML = 'click';
  
            }
  
        }
  
    });
```

Comment: что мешает сделать image2.addEventListener ?

Comment: @Artsiom  image2 внутри конструктора, (вокруг основных картинок (а их 10) вращаются несколько "спутников"-картинок, так не получается..

Comment: попробуй так `image2.addEventListener(ev, function)` перед `context.drawImage(image2, (this.x -  this.Lradius) + vx, (this.y -  this.Lradius) + vy, this.Lradius*2, this.Lradius*2);`,

Comment: второй вариант более првильный делегирование повесить на `canvas.addEventListener`

Comment: @Artsiom не взлетает, по-моему внутри цикла такой метод не сработает..

Comment: да, тут все куд проще оказалось, придется искать библиотеку для работы с canvas) тк canvas не может иметь внутри себя html элементов, следовательн ои события вешать не на что... или по координатам искать, смому писать, вот примерчик http://jsfiddle.net/BmeKr/